# actualizar campo select mediante ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

estoy comenzando a utilizar codeigniter, javascript con la librería jquery y tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un formulario y en el un campo select donde cargo las ciudades mando los datos desde mi controlador en json, de la sgt forma.

```js
function LlenarCombo(){
       $.post('http://localhost/app/ciudad/getCiudades', 
       function (data){
          var c = JSON.parse(data);
          $.each(c, function(i, item){
                $('#ciudad').append('<option value="'+item.Id_ciudad+'">'+item.Nombre+'</option>');
          });
       });
    }
```

el caso es que al lado del select tengo un boton con la opcion de poder agregar una nueva ciudad, el metedo funciona bien y guarda bien los datos, mi problema es que necesito que al guardar se actualize el campo select sin recargar la pagina.

```js
function guardarCiudad(){
      $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost/app/ciudad/Guardar',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#formCiudad').serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
           $('#modalCiudad').modal('hide');
           alert(data);
           LlenarCombo();
           $("#formCiudad")[0].reset();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error al guardar los datos');
        }
      });
    }
```

al llamar la funcion en el succes, obiamente me repite los datos, que otra cosa puedo realizar?

Comment: Limpiarlo en el succes antes de volver a llenarlo

Comment: algo asi funcionaris? $("#ciudad")[0].reset(); ese es el id de mi campo select

Comment: $("#ciudad").empty(); éso eliminaria todos los options para que cuando leas nuevamente no se repita el nuevo

Comment: @federhico muchas gracias pude resolver mi problema

Answer (score 2):

Te doy 2 ocpiones

1: limpias ti ID ciudad con :

```
$("#ciudad").empty();
```

2: Matar todos los eventos que tengas corriendo :

```
$('#ciudad').unbind();
```